# Obtain the frequency of an interpolated numpy array (using fft)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, fft

I would like to obtain the frequency of numerical data. Since the data is not equally spaced, I must interpolate it to calculate the Fourier transform. When I get the frequency, I notice that it varies depending on the maximum time in which it is interpolated.

For example, I have tried to obtain the frequency of a sine function:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate

t =np.linspace(0, 200, num=2000)
func = np.sin(t)

#Interpolate the function
tmax = 150
fintep = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(t, func)
TimeInterp = np.linspace(0, tmax, num=10000)
funcInterp = fintep(TimeInterp)

#sampling rate
FsInterp = 1/((TimeInterp[1]-TimeInterp[0]))

#fft
fftInterp = np.fft.fft(funcInterp)
f1Interp = 2*fftInterp[0:int(np.ceil((len(fftInterp)+1)/2))-1]
discrfreqInterp = np.linspace(0,FsInterp/2,1+int(FsInterp/2/(FsInterp/len(fftInterp)))-1)
f1Interp  = f1Interp /(2*len(discrfreqInterp)) 
fpos1Interp = np.where(abs(f1Interp )==max(abs(f1Interp )))
freqfftInterp = discrfreqInterp [fpos1Interp]

freqfftInterp
```

My problem is that depending on the value of the `tmax`, the frequency shows a variation. Is there any way to improve the accuracy?

Comment: Did you mean `f1Interp = 2*fftInterp[1:int(...`? Otherwise you're doubling the DC component, which doesn't sound right

Comment: I am pretty sure that `discrfreqInterp` has a mistake in it. Consider using something like `np.fft.rfftfreq(fftInterp.size, FsInterp)` or so. In fact, you can probably replace `fft` with `rfft` for simplicity as well.

Comment: Also, when you sample at different rates, the nearest frequency bin to the true value will be different. Plot two absolute FFTs with different `tmax` on top of each other to see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks I'll try. The thing is that I would expect to observe a resolution of 0.01 or 0.001 or even better.

Comment: When I use `tmax` 100, 150 and 200, I get the exact same value printed out at the end. I'm guessing that what you are seeing is an effect of the rectangular window. Plot the magnitude of the FFT to see the effect. You need to apply a window function to your data.

Comment: but If you use tmax equal to 140, 160 or 180 you obtain different frequencies.  I have applied Hanning windows and the frequency still varies.